Is there a simple basic way to navigate the file system in emacs avoiding dired?
I have been trying to find a way to do simple file-system navigation as can be done using most command line interfaces such as
cd sourcetext
To change the current directory to one of its subdirectories without having to type the full path.
The help I have seen recommends such things as dired, helm or ido.
Is there otherwise a simple way, avoiding the invocation of a complete mode or software package, to merely change from the current directory to the next?
In other words, what is the simplest and most basic way in emacs to achieve the equivalents of:
dir
and
cd just_the_subdirectory_name?
PS. I am new user so please don't annihilate me for me making rookie mistakes.

Current-directory in Emacs is called default-directory and is a per buffer variable, not per Emacs process. To set it manually you can either use "cd" command as Drew suggests or you can just setf it as for any other variable:
(setf default-directory "path/to/some/directory").

However, that is not idiomatic Emacs usage. Typically we are working with buffers and files in Emacs and let Emacs manage the default-dirextory for us. You can simply do M-x find-file (C-x C-f), and type the path to the file or navigate to the file via completing read. In, your case since you don't want to use completion (?), you would just type that path in the minibuffer.
If you wish to create a new file, you would still use find-file, and it will create it for you. You can even just type directories that do not exist, and Emacs will ask you if you want to create them. Find-file is thus a do-what-I-mean style of function, that tries to automate stuff for us.
There is very little reason to first "navigate" to a directory in Dired just to open a file. Dired is typically used if you want to see which files are present in a directory, some details about files or if you wish to "manage" files (rename, delete, copy, sync etc). But the idiomatic workflow is not  to "cd" to a directory prior to opening a file.
When it comes to completing read, and completion frameworks like Helm, I don't understand why you wouldn't want to use them? Those frameworks are there to save you typing.
In the case of Helm, it has advantage of having a good interface to manage files directly from Helm completion buffer if you want to use helm-find-files. You will be presented with a list of files in which you can mark a file, or several, and than invoke typical file manage operations, so there is no need to use Dired much if you are using Helm.
I think your question sounds like XY-question. What is the purpose of managing the working directory manually? Which problem are you trying to solve?

Well, I just think, intuitively, there /should/ be some emacs alternative to the command-line "cd" (change directory) command which can take only the name of a subdirectory as an argument. If I am in my home directory on a command line and I want to navigate to a subdirectory called "texts" all I do is "cd texts". What I want is to find what is the way to achieve the same thing with emacs.

The command exists (and is indeed named cd); but as mentioned in this answer, the default-directory value is buffer-local -- Emacs doesn't have any global notion of "the current directory", because it's not globally acting in any single directory -- every buffer has its own context.  So you can cd to another directory within a buffer (and then, say, C-x C-f from that directory), but (a) if it's a file-visiting buffer then you've just created a weird disconnect between buffer-file-name and default-directory; and (b) no other buffer is affected.

Which isn't to say that M-x cd isn't useful (I certainly use it on occasion); but you would only use it if the effect it has is the thing you want.  If you don't want to mess with the current buffer's context then note that the dired and find-file commands prompt you the same way, and won't mess with the buffer you started in.

To borrow the original analogy with a command-line shell, think of each Emacs buffer as a separate terminal running its own shell.  If you have multiple terminals each running a shell, you can cd to another directory in any of those shells, but it only affects the shell in the terminal you were typing in.  None of the shells in your other terminals will change their directory as a result.

OK, thanks for the advice. I don't mind at all that the current-directory is buffer-local. The issue is that as an emacs noob I start to hit the buffers quickly when it appears to be that things such as the most basic file-system navigation commands are incredibly cumbersome to use. For something with such a deep history I would have thought those sorts of function were added to emacs very early in its development, maybe even from the first version.

It's puzzling for me to read through the advice and find such things as M-x make-directory RET dir/to/create RET to create a directory in emacs when I can just md directory_name on a command line.

If you think in terms of Emacs being a 40+ years old application, it should be natural that by now, people have solved basic UX problems? Don't you think so? If you are totally new to Emacs, and think things are strange, don't you think it could be on your side? Another question: how many other text editors, or in general applications, let you navigate the file system as you do in a shell? Or let you manage files? Isn't Emacs quite unique in that regard? Why should Emacs have alternative to cd command? The default UX is find-file function. The rest is icing on the cake.

You can also execute shell commands directly from mini-buffer in Emacs: M-! md directory-name will do it. Also M-! cd some-directory. I think it is a bad practice if you are going to change working directory via shell. Sooner or later it will bite you back because you will forget that your default-directory is something else than the directory where the buffer is, and you will perform some action in a wrong directory. That is what @phils warns about strange disconnect between buffer-file-name and default-directory.

Of course the standard (Unix) shell command for making a directory is named mkdir not md, and in Emacs mkdir is an alias for make-directory -- so you can M-x mkdir (which seems plenty intuitive to me).  But if you want to alias md to make-directory as well, then you can do that too.

If you really want the shell UI, you can just M-x shell and use your command line UI muscle memory inside Emacs.  For normal shells it will track the directory of the shell, so you can mkdir and cd to your heart's content in the shell, and then C-x C-f from the shell buffer to visit a file in that directory, etc.

@myname "If you think in terms of Emacs being a 40+ years old application, it should be natural that by now, people have solved basic UX problems? Don't you think so? If you are totally new to Emacs, and think things are strange, don't you think it could be on your side?"
Well, yes. I had assumed it would be and that these problems would have been solved very early in its evolution. That's exactly why I asked: I expected it to be more intuitive and not imply use of plugin packages.

@GeorginaDavenport IMO, not to be impolite and arrogant, bt what you described is not an Emacs UX problem, rather a user problem. Can you point out any other application aside shells (bash, csh, korn, cmd.exe etc), that has the workflow you describe? Yet, there was a way to do what you want you were just not aware of it (Drews answer for example). In other words, I am not sure what is "unsolved problem" here. Emacs is a complex application, disguised into a simple text editor.

OK, well clearly the SO rules forbid us from having a long discussion about this so I will let the matter rest soon. To continue on your point though: You write "Can you point out any other application aside shells (bash, csh, korn, cmd.exe etc), that has the workflow".
You appear to have asserted an arbitrary condition "outside shells" as if I should expect basic navigation features to exist nowhere else or should prove the contrary.
Seems to me, with its pedigree, that it should be a realistic expectation that simple file navigation should also exist /within emacs' basic features/.

Yes, unfortunately comments on SO are not optimal way to discuss things. If you want to talk more about the issue I think at this point the best would be to send the email to emacs-devel at gnu dot org. They will probably give you more detailed explanation why things are as they are, and you skip the 500 char restriction of SO comments. Best regards.

Just use Emacs command cd: M-x cd (or bind it to a key).
C-h f cd:

cd is an interactive compiled Lisp function in files.el.
(cd DIR)
Make DIR become the current buffer's default directory.
If your environment includes a CDPATH variable, try each one of
that list of directories (separated by occurrences of
path-separator) when resolving a relative directory name.
The path separator is colon in GNU and GNU-like systems.

You also have command pwd.
How to find such info on your own: C-h r RET to get into the Emacs manual.  Then i cd RET to look up cd in the index and take you directly to the manual page that documents it, which is page Node Names.
